# Dependencies not injected directly into private fields in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

On my `appsettings.json` file, I have a section like below:

```
"MongoDbSettings": {
   "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:127.0.0.1",
   "DatabaseName": "ComparisonDb"
}
```

And, I have a custom class which can handle above two sub sections.

```
public interface IMongoDbSetting
{
    string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class MongoDbSetting : IMongoDbSetting
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

I make below definitions on My `Startup.cs` file:

```
        services.Configure<MongoDbSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings"));

        //...

        services.AddSingleton<IMongoDbSetting>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDbSetting>>().Value);

        services.AddControllers();
```

And, I have a UserRepository class which returns the correct DB Provider's Repository class provided by a variable:

```
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<User>
    {
        private SqlServerDbContext _dbContext;
        private IMongoDbSetting mongoDbSetting; //DI doesn't fill this up

        public IOperation<User> GetRepository(DbType dbType)
        {
            if (dbType == DbType.SqlServer)
            {
                if (_dbContext == null)
                {
                    _dbContext = new SqlServerDbContext();
                }

                return new DbFactory<SqlServerDbContext, User>(_dbContext).GetDb(dbType);
            }
            else if (dbType == DbType.MongoDB)
            {
                return new DbFactory<SqlServerDbContext, User>(mongoDbSetting).GetDb(dbType);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Undefined DB provider");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, `IMongoDbSetting` is always null despite of my definitions on my Startup file. I need to pass my `MongoDbSetting` class to `DbFactory` as in the end `MongoDbRepositoryBase` requires this file in its constructor. Below, you can see the other two classes.

DbFactory:

```
    public class DbFactory<C, T> where C : BaseDataContext where T : class
    {
        public C _baseDataContext;
        public IMongoDbSetting _mongoDbSetting;

        public DbFactory(IMongoDbSetting mongoDbSetting)
        {
            _mongoDbSetting = mongoDbSetting;
        }

        public DbFactory(C baseDataContext)
        {
            _baseDataContext = baseDataContext;
        }

        public IOperation<T> GetDb(DbType dbType)
        {
            switch (dbType)
            {
                case DbType.SqlServer:
                    return new SqlServerRepositoryBase<C, T>(_baseDataContext);
                case DbType.MongoDB:
                    return new MongoDbRepositoryBase<T>(_mongoDbSetting);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbType), "Undefined DB provider");
            }
        }
    }
```

MongoDbRepositoryBase:

```
    public class MongoDbRepositoryBase<T> : IOperation<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

        public MongoDbRepositoryBase(IMongoDbSetting settings)
        {
            IMongoDatabase database = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString).GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

            _collection = database.GetCollection<T>(GetCollectionName(typeof(T)));
        }

       //CRUD methods
    }
```

Comment: Does `UserRepository` have a constructor that I'm missing?

Comment: @JosephRT no, it doesn't have

Comment: You should check [No need for Repositories and Unit of Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) and [Repository is the new Signleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core's DI only supports constructor injection, as far as I'm aware.  So you'd need something akin to

```
public UserRepository(IMongoDbSetting mongoDbSetting, ...) {
    _mongoDbSetting = mongoDbSetting;
    // and so on
}
```

for the DI to inject what you want.

Or alternatively (I personally wouldn't take this route, but it's an option) you can have your code ask the `ServiceProvider` directly to provide an instance, there's an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-services-from-main).

As a side note, your `_mongoDbSettings` field is also `private`.  I believe that DI frameworks that can do field injection need it to be at least protected.  Might be wrong, but it's something to keep in mind for the future.